# Extended knapsack: is it NP-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard, knapsack-problems

I have a problem of this form coming from an application domain, similar to the classical knapsack problem but not quite the same:

Maximize the value of

($\sum_{i=1}^n v_i \cdot x_i) + B \cdot \frac{W}{r}$

subject to

$ \sum_{i=1}^n w_i \cdot x_i \leq W$.

Here, $W$ and $B$ are constants, and $r$ is an integer variable with $1 \leq r \leq n$, whose behavior vis-à-vis the variables $v_i$ and $w_i$ is unknown to me.

It is obvious that if $B$ is 0, this reduces to the classical knapsack and is hence NP-complete, but is it still NP-complete otherwise?  Can we say anything about this problem considering possible behaviors of $r$?

It's been a while since I studied algorithms; please bear with me if this looks too simple (let me clarify that this question arose from research; I'm not a kid trying to cheat on homework).  I have also not found an answer in the responses to other knapsack questions asked on this forum.

Comment: You haven't told us what is fixed (what are the inputs) and what we're allowed to choose (what is the desired output).  Are the $v_i,w_i$'s constants that are provided in the input?  $W$?  $B$?  $r$?  Also, I think your first step should be to figure out how $r$ depends on $v_i,w_i$, and then ask about a specific instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$B*\frac{W}{r}$ is a constant, so adding it to your objective function has no effect on the solution. The problem is NP-complete, regardless of the values of $B$ and $r$.

Comment: No, it is not a constant, because $r$ is a variable.  (Let me clarify that $r$ in particular varies with the values of $w_i$ and $v_i$, though I cannot tell in what way.) I think you gave some other answer first?

Comment: I initially misread the problem statement. For a particular instance of the problem (fixed $v_i$ and $w_i$), $r$ is constant so we may disregard the term $B\frac{W}{r}$ when solving the problem. Or does $r$ somehow depend on $x_i$ as well?

Comment: Yes, that is a degenerate case, but if we have to choose the values of the variables the simplification does not apply, and this is where the problem lies.

Comment: So exactly what values are you trying to solve for? Since you stated this is a knapsack problem, I assumed $v_i$ (the values) and $w_i$ (the weights) were part of the problem input, and you were trying to solve for $x_i$ (a binary variable indicating whether to take item $i$ or not) and that $r$ depended on the values of $w_i$ and $v_i$. Since $w_i$ and $v_i$ are part of the input, isn't $r$ decided at the time the input is given, and the term is thus constant for any particular instance of the problem?

Comment: Yes, I believe you're right.  Thanks.  I may have other related queries (re more varieties of knapsack) later.